# XSD: multiple groups with the same elements

Tags: php, xml, scope, xsd, multiple-definition-error

I am attempting to validate XML that can only be read, not changed. I know what is possible in the XML and its structure, but not what will be received. Some of these have elements with the same name as others, either being exactly the same, or having different types, etc.

Is there a way to remove the groups from the scope of each other, or will I have to separate the XML, validate the chunks separately, and so on? I have provided an example of one of my attempts below for clarification of what I am attempting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="8" minOccurs="8" name="request">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
              <xs:group ref="group1"/>
              <xs:group ref="group2"/>
              <xs:group ref="group3"/>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:group name="group1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="hello" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="group2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="hello" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="world" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="group3">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="hello" minOccurs="0" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="world" minOccurs="0" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please explain this statement: *I know what is possible in the XML and its structure, but not what will be received*

Comment: I know what group 1, 2, and 3 will look like, but I don't know what order they will be in, whether or not they will be in there multiple times, or whether they will be there at all.

Comment: Please show a sample of this XML document that cannot be changed. Why did you tag this question with PHP, by the way?

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I tagged the question with PHP because I am using schemaValidateSource() in PHP to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have elements with the same name but different types in a single content model, `request` in your particular case.

You could get around this constraint by making your `group1`, `group2`, and `group3` actually be elements in the XML rather than merely groups in the XSD.

If you cannot change the XML, then you've adopted an ambiguous grammar that XSD won't be able to help you validate without going more general than you'd probably prefer.  For example, you might use `xsd:any` or generalize `world` to be a simple type which could accommodate all cases -- `xs:string` might work.

Comment: I was afraid there wasn't a way around this for PHP yet, and you are correct, I can't change the XML. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @dabuda: You're welcome.  Note that the issue exists at the XML/XSD level and is independent of PHP or any other implementation.